# Need to pull distinct tuples from a relation in PIG regardless of order i.e. (1,2)=(2,1)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am very new to using Pig and Hadoop, so please forgive me if this is very basic. I have a relation that has a list of users and followers (like Twitter) with the format (userA,userB) meaning that userB follows userA. My assignment (yes this is homework) is to find people who follow each other. I have done this, t I have twice as many tuples as I need since I have (userA,userB) and (userB,userA) in the relation. It doesn't matter which of the two tuples I end up with, I just need to eliminate one of them. The DISTINCT keyword won't do me any good since the order is reversed

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have already tried.

Comment: Jeremy I haven't gotten very far. Most of my ideas have been to make a copy of the relation and join or cogroup the two, but this just results in more duplication without any way to identify one of the tuples without getting the other. I went from two tuples (1,2) and (2,1) to two tuples with more fields ({1,2},{2,1}) and ({2,1},{1,2}). which just left me with duplication in the tuple as well as from tuple to tuple. I don't know where to start on this really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it seems you could try sorting the fields of the tuple before de-duplicating, like this:

```
X = FOREACH A GENERATE (f1 < f2 ? f1 : f2), (f1 < f2 ? f2 : f1);
Y = DISTINCT X;
```